AKS fetching K8s Deprecated APIs List
I need to fetch the list of Kubernetes Deprecated API within a cluster. This can be done from the Azure Dashboard by going to the AKS Resource > Diagnosis and Solve Problems > Create, Upgrade, Delete and Scale > Kubernetes Deprecation APIs. You can see that menu in the options below.
Question; (I only have Read Access to the Cluster and Azure Portal)

How can I query this list of Deprecated APIs using the Azure SDK/CLI or their REST API?
How to cloud providers find out the deprecated APIs? Is it through Logs or through the manifest files for the resources within the Cluster.

See the image here
I tried using the Azure Advisor but it wouldn't return information on the Deprecated APIs within the Kubernetes Cluster. I've been going through the documentation and Googling my way through it but it seems that it isn't possible.

To fetch deprecated k8s api within aks cluster you can use
kubectl api-resources


Kubernetes doesn't provide a direct command to list deprecated APIs, but you can check the APIs and compare them manually against the K8s deprecation guidelines.
You can also create a bash script and check of depricated API if any
#!/bin/bash

# Get all API groups and versions
api_groups=$(kubectl api-versions)

# Loop through each API group and version
for group in $api_groups; do
  echo "Checking API group version: $group"
  
  # Try to get the resources for each API group version
  if [[ "$group" == "v1" ]]; then
    resources=$(kubectl get --raw "/api/v1" 2>/dev/null)
  else
    resources=$(kubectl get --raw "/apis/$group" 2>/dev/null)
  fi
  
  # Check if the resources exist
  if [ -n "$resources" ]; then
    # Parse the resources using jq to find deprecated ones
    deprecated_resources=$(echo $resources | jq '.resources[] | select(.deprecated==true) | {name, groupVersion: "'$group'", kind}')
    if [ -n "$deprecated_resources" ]; then
      echo "Deprecated resources found for API group version: $group"
      echo $deprecated_resources
    else
      echo "No deprecated resources found for API group version: $group"
    fi
  else
    echo "No resources found for API group version: $group"
  fi
done



To use the REST API, you can make a GET request to the following endpoint:

    https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/{managedClusterName}/agentPools/{agentPoolName}/kubeletConfig/deprecatedAPIs?api-version=2021-11-01


from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient

from kubernetes import client, config

  

# Initialize Azure credentials and AKS client

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

subscription_id = "abcd-efg-hijk-lmno-pqrstuv"

resource_group_name = "arkorg"

cluster_name = "arkoaks"

  

aks_client = ContainerServiceClient(credential, subscription_id)

  

# Get the AKS cluster

aks_cluster = aks_client.managed_clusters.get(resource_group_name, cluster_name)

  

# Get Kubernetes configuration from AKS cluster

config.load_kube_config()

  

# Initialize Kubernetes client

k8s_client = client.ApiClient()

  

# List all API groups and versions

api_instance = client.ApisApi(k8s_client)

api_groups = api_instance.get_api_versions()

  

# Process the API groups to find deprecated ones

deprecated_apis = []

for group in api_groups.groups:

if group.preferred_version:

version = group.preferred_version.version

if  'deprecated'  in group.preferred_version.version:

deprecated_apis.append({

'group': group.name,

'version': version

})

  

print("Deprecated APIs:", deprecated_apis)


References:

Upgrade an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster - Check for available AKS cluster upgrades
Stop Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster upgrades automatically on API breaking changes - Mitigate stopped upgrade operations
Access Kubernetes resources from the Azure portal - Troubleshooting
API Deprecations in Azure Container Registry
Basic troubleshooting of AKS cluster creation issues - View cluster insights


Hey,
Thanks for helping me out here.
A couple things I'd like to add here,

There is no api-version=2021-11-01, therefore the REST API route doesn't seem to work.
Ideally i would want to not go into the hassle of running commands inside the cluster. I want to be able to get the API Deprecation Information from directly an Azure API or their SDK or CLI, that way I can use it for the larger goal I'm trying to achieve.


I see. This is what best I could find to track the depricated API.

Np, thanks alot though
